# How to create TreeView in Angular 2 using Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview

What should I do to create TreeView in Angular 2 using TypesScript?

I am trying to find out on Google but still not get any working example etc.

Can anyone please share me example to achieve this task?

Comment: you mean like this one, that appears as the first result when searching for angular2 tree component ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tree-component

Comment: Actually, I want to display parent and child using "angular2 tree component" and also drag and drop one parent child to other..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use a ready made one, for example angular2-tree-component?

`npm install angular2-tree-component`

Comment: I am using the same but not able to achieve. I am looking an example, where I can see and understand. Actually, I new in Angular 2 So..

Comment: There is documentation for that component here https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs .

Please consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Hello @Alexander, Is it possible to drag and drop one parent's child node to other?

Comment: The developer says it will be supported in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this article](https://medium.com/@nicuvlad89/simple-angular-tree-like-structure-afabef433d33).

It will help you to create a tree structure without a third party library. It works recursively and it has collapsible logic.

Comment: Its awesome, Simple solution. Thanks @NicuVlad

Comment: Great works man! One question, how do I dynamically add data to a node's children?

Comment: Really Simple and helpful.